How to use a TableCellRenderer to display an object in a table in Swing
I'm making a todolist app and I'm displaying all the tasks on a JTable(which only has one row), I also added a RowFilter to the JTable inorder to sort the tasks based on different categories. I created a class implementing the TableCellRenderer to only print the task name and the days left to the tasks deadline. Here's where the problem is, I want the user to be able to click on a task(or tasks) and then choose what to do with that task, but it seems like I can't click on any row on the table, I don't know what the problem is
This is my code for the JTable, The table model I used and the custom cell renderer I made
package com.daniel.todolist.gui.todolist_components;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import com.daniel.todolist.db_objs.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ContentPage extends JPanel {
    private java.util.List<Task> tasks;
    private JTable tasksTable;
    private TableRowSorter<MyTableModel> sorter;
    private boolean pressingCTRL = false;
    private KeyListener keyListener;
    private MouseAdapter tableMouseListener;
    Vector selectedCells = new Vector<int[]>();

    public ContentPage(java.util.List<Task> tasks) {
        super();
        this.tasks = tasks;
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setupContentPage();
    }

    public void setupContentPage(){
        MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();    // this is my custom table model 
        tasksTable = new JTable(model);
        tasksTable.setDefaultRenderer(Task.class, new TaskCellRenderer());
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
        tasksTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
        // call the something() method to setup the mouse and key listener
        something();
        tasksTable.addKeyListener(keyListener);
        tasksTable.addMouseListener(tableMouseListener);
        add(new JScrollPane(tasksTable));
    }

    // I didn't know how to implement row selection, I got this function from another stack question
    public void something(){

        keyListener = new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL){
                    pressingCTRL = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL){
                    pressingCTRL = false;
                }
            }
        };

        tableMouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                if(pressingCTRL){   // check if the user is pressing the control key
                    int row = tasksTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                    int col = tasksTable.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                    int[] newEntry = new int[]{row, col};
                    // print out the entry so we can see what it is
                    System.out.println(newEntry);   // this didn't print out anything
                    if(selectedCells.contains(newEntry)){
                        selectedCells.remove(newEntry);
                    }
                    else{
                        selectedCells.add(newEntry);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    // this is my function for filtering the table, this method is called and a category is passed
    public void filterTable(String category){
        RowFilter<AbstractTableModel, Object> filter =  null;

        filter = new RowFilter<AbstractTableModel, Object>(){
            @Override 
            public boolean include(Entry<? extends AbstractTableModel, ? extends Object> entry){
                Task task = (Task) entry.getValue(0);
                if(category == "ASSIGNED"){
                    return task.getUserId() != task.getAssigned_by();
                }
                else if(category == "IMPORTANT"){
                    return task.getIsImportant();
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };

        sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
    }
     

    // this is my custom table model 
    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"Tasks"};
        // I changed the tasks fromm a list to a 2D array
        private Object[][] data = tasks.stream()
                                        .map(element -> new Object[]{element})
                                        .toArray(Object[][]::new);
        private Class<?>[] columnClasses = { Task.class };

        public String getColumnName(int c){
            return this.columnNames[c];
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return this.columnNames.length;
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return (Task) data[row][col];
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return this.data.length;
        }

        // JTable uses this method to figure out the default renderer for each cell
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) { 
            return columnClasses[c];
        }
    }

}


class TaskCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
    private Font labelFont = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 17);

    public TaskPanel() {
        super();
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
                Task task = (Task) value;
                String text = task.getTaskName() + " | " + task.getDaysLeft();
                setText(text);
                return this;
    }
}

After I tried this, I couldn't select the any of the rows on the table at all. even the function I made didn't work.
When I click on a cell, I expected to print out an integer array of the row and column index but it doesn't do that

You are, in fact, selecting rows—you just can’t see it.  Notice how the TableCellRenderer method has an isSelected argument?  Your renderer is not doing anything with it, so it renders selected and unselected rows in exactly the same manner.
You could write code to account for this… but you don’t have to, because DefaultTableCellRenderer already accounts for all of the arguments.  Just extend that:
class TaskCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private Font labelFont = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 17);

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {

        Task task = (Task) value;
        String text = task.getTaskName() + " | " + task.getDaysLeft();
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, text,
            isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }
}

And of course, remove your custom KeyListener and MouseListener.  JTable already fully supports row selection.  You’ll only interfere with that.
CAUTION:  These two lines will fail.
if(category == "ASSIGNED"){
else if(category == "IMPORTANT"){

The correct way to compare strings is:
if (Objects.equals(category, "ASSIGNED")) {
else if (Objects.equals(category, "IMPORTANT")) {

The Objects.equals method is in the java.util.Objects class.
You can also write it this way, since an equals method will always return false without throwing an exception, even if passed a null argument:
if ("ASSIGNED".equals(category))) {
else if ("IMPORTANT".equals(category))) {

Do not reverse the above comparisons.  category.equals("ASSIGNED") is not the same thing—it will throw a NullPointerException if category happens to be null.
(The same caution will apply to return task.getUserId() != task.getAssigned_by(); if the userId and assignedBy properties are Strings.)

Thanks a lot, it works now. Is there a way to also apply the labelFont to the renderer. (Also, thanks a lot for the warning).

DefaultTableCellRenderer extends JLabel, so you can just call its setFont method.
